# See columns in non-alphabetic order in data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to see the choice of columns of data in the photo in the order of the file and not in alphabetical order.

[image]

How to do that?

TY

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible unfortunately. If you really want to, you can prefix the column name with 01. 02. 03. to order the fields but otherwise the search bar can be useful to find what you need.

You could also use display folders to organise related columns.

You can vote for the idea here: https://ideas.fabric.microsoft.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=64dd672c-cc9e-4836-982f-6a4f20df9fab